# Upload directory for a field instance

Tags: nodes, entities

I've been searching a lot for this, but no luck. 
I've created a custom file field along with an instance for my custom content type in the .install file.

I've set up everything except that I want that by default this instance of the file file that I created to upload to the 'private' directory and if it's not defined, to define it with this module.

```
  $file_download_link_instance = array(
  'field_name' => 'file_download_link',
  'required' => true,
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'bundle' => $machine_name,
  'label' => t('Files to upload'),
  'settings' => array(
    'file_extensions' => 'txt doc docx pdf ods odt xls xls png jpg jpeg',
    'description_field' => TRUE,
    ),
  'description' => t('Please upload here the files.'),
  'display' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'type' => 'hidden',
      ),
    'teaser' => array(
      'type' => 'hidden',
      ),
  ),
  'locked' => TRUE,
);
```

I believe that I have to edit the 'settings' array, but I don't know the syntax.
Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you might benefit from looking at the [examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples)? Have a browse of the [file example](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/5b0687a193c9f31db2706c8552588bb22221ae36:/file_example/file_example.module) module.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I couldn't find any relevant information any of the submodules of the examples project.

Answer (score 0):

You just wanted to add attribute *`file_directory`* inside the *`settings`* array

```
  'settings' => array(
    'file_directory' => 'myModule/images',
    ),
```

Here is other attributes that might be added:

```
  'settings' => array(
    'file_extensions' => 'png jpg jpeg',
    'file_directory' => '',
    'max_filesize' => '20 MB',
    'alt_field' => 1,
    'title_field' => 1,
    'max_resolution' => '300x200',
    'min_resolution' => '200x125',
    'default_image' => 0,
  ),
```